# Boost threads creating InterlockedCompareExchange Errors on mingw32

Tags: c++, boost-asio

After googling for InterlockedCompareExchange errors, it seems like it always points to an old error for mingw64, and I am using mingw32.

It seems to happen to all examples that use threads, but if I just have "`#include <boost/thread.hpp>`" and no calls of a thread it will work, so I think I did the linking correct.

This is my build:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in UDP_EXAMPLE (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -g -IC:\boost_1_56_0 -c "C:\Users\poteto\Desktop\Other Programming\UDP_EXAMPLE\server.cpp" -o obj\server.o
In file included from C:\boost_1_56_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:0,
                 from C:\boost_1_56_0/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15,
                 from C:\boost_1_56_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from C:\boost_1_56_0/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from C:\Users\poteto\Desktop\Other Programming\UDP_EXAMPLE\server.cpp:5:
C:\boost_1_56_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp:180:0: warning: ignoring #pragma intrinsic  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
mingw32-g++.exe  -o Debug\http_server.exe obj\server.o  -lws2_32 -lwsock32  C:\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_56.a C:\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_56.a
C:\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_56.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail5win3223GetTickCount64emulationEv+0x1e): undefined reference to `_InterlockedCompareExchange'
C:\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_56.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail5win3223GetTickCount64emulationEv+0x70): undefined reference to `_InterlockedCompareExchange'
C:\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_56.a(thread.o):thread.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail5win3223GetTickCount64emulationEv+0xb5): undefined reference to `_InterlockedCompareExchange'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
3 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

I linked the libraries: libboost_thread and libboost_system. I am using Codeblocks. Other asio examples without threads work.

In the example:http://www.ce.unipr.it/~medici/udpserver2.html

If I were to remove the call to the thread, it would work.

Comment: 1st Google hit: http://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2014/08/27642.php

Comment: Quote: "Personally, I consider mingw.org
broken".  He's not the only person, a lot of programmers appear to have moved to mingw-w64.

Comment: Yea, ill add the patch https://github.com/boostorg/thread/commit/26042ca26a9783c9055a40ada6b8bb26d3dd65b6#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

Comment: And it works after building it!